# How to attach data from one array to another in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, for-loop

I am building a [post, comments] project where post details are stored in posts table and comment details are stored in comments table. The project is generated in Laravel(Php). Here is the piece of code.

```
//get data from Post table
$posts = $this->postsRepo->getAllPosts();
//get data from comments table
$comments = $this->commentRepo->getAllComments();
print_r($posts);
print_r($comments);
```

The result of post table

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [post_text] => This is a test post
        )
)
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [post_text] => This is another test
        )
)
```

The result of comments table

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [post_id] => 1
            [comments_text] => This is a test comment 1
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [post_id] => 1
            [comments_text] => This is a test comment 2
        )
)
```

Now I want result like

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [post_title] => This is a test post         
        [comments] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [post_id] => 1
                        [comment_text] => This is a test comment 1
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [post_id] => 1
                        [comment_text] => This is a test comment 2 
                    )
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [post_title] => This is another test
        [comments] => Array()
    )

)
```

I've used following technique, and it is working

```
foreach ($posts as $postIndex => $post) {
    foreach ($comments as $commentIndex => $comment) {
        if($post->id == $comment->post_id) {
            $posts[$postIndex]->comments[] = $comment;
        }
    }
}
```

There's another way like running comments inside **post** for loop. I'll send the post_id to comments table. But this technique will be slow, as data increases

**Could anybody please suggest a better technology to solve this issue?**
Also, I used Repository design pattern for getting posts & comments

Comment: why you not use laravel relationship? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: define relationship in your Post Model and give name comments  change your query PostModel::with('comments')->get();

Comment: I am not using Eloquent. Using simple DB queries

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Ditch the repo design pattern and use eloquent. It does the same thing and already has the code to do this for you available.

Comment: I am using Php 7.0

Comment: I can't ditch Repository Design pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this, depending on the version of PHP your using (although 1 will always work).  The main principle is to index one of the arrays by the ID so that instead of looping over both arrays, you can use an index to set the values.  As each post can have multiple comments, it seemed easier to index the posts by the ID and loop over the comments adding them into the correct post...

```
$posts = [
    (object)[
        "id" => 1,
        "post_text" => "This is a test post"
    ],
    (object)[
        "id" => 2,
        "post_text" => "This is another test"
    ]
];

$comments = [(object)
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "post_id" => 1,
        "comments_text" => "This is a test comment 1"
        ],
    (object)
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "post_id" => 1,
        "comments_text" => "This is a test comment 2"
        ]
    ];

$postIndex = array_column($posts, null, "id");   
//$postIndex = array_reduce($posts, function ($result, $post) { // PHP pre 7
//    $result[$post->id] = $post;
//    return $result;
//}, array());
foreach ( $comments as $comment )   {
    $postIndex[ $comment->post_id ]->comments[] = $comment;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($postIndex);
```

Outputs...

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [post_text] => This is a test post
            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [post_id] => 1
                            [comments_text] => This is a test comment 1
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [post_id] => 1
                            [comments_text] => This is a test comment 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [post_text] => This is another test
        )

)
```

The only difference is that from PHP 7.0, you can use `array_column()` with an array of objects.  Prior to that you had to manually do the conversion.

Comment: I think your comment id 2 is at the wrong place. I believe "post_id" in comments array says which post it relates to

Comment: @Andreas, thanks - I was errrr... only testing to see if anyone was watching >;)

Comment: I have 2 more table (Post likes, comment likes). Want to connect Posts like with posts array (like we connected comments) & comments like in comments array

Comment: One more table is attached. Now table structure will go like this Users->Posts->Comments. What to be used for this? Please help me

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to sort this out till tomorrow.  You may be better off asking a new question with the code so far and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay. Please try it tomorrow. Requirements are User->Post, Post->likes & Comments array and Comments will have comment likes array.

Comment: I need to know the data coming from these two new tables.  May be easier to ask a new question as there may be a better way of dealing with deeper levels of layers.

Answer (score 0):

You better use eloquent relationships...
but to answer your question for current case, if you need to accomplish this in php way.

```
// for all the post of the posts array
    foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {

        // get comments which only belongs to the post
        $post_comments = [];
        foreach ($comments as $comment) {

            if ($comment['post_id'] == $value['id']) {
                array_push($post_comments, $comment);
            }
        }

        // add a new attribute (comments) to each post
        // set created comments array of the post
        $post[$key]['comments'] = $post_comments;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you loop posts then you can use array_intersect and array_intersect_key.
This means you only loop one array once but use array functions to get the correct comments.
This means the arrays have to be arrays and not objects.

```
Foreach($posts as $key => $post){
    $matches = array_intersect(array_column($comments, "post_id"), [$post["id"]]);
    $new[$key][] = $post;
    $new[$key]["comments"][] = array_intersect_key($comments, $matches);
}

Var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/eq20D